# ionic, $state.go does not change the view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

in my ionic app after successful registration an `$ionicPopup.alert` shown and by pressing OK I want to navigate to another state. the **url changes** but the view remains on the registration form.
 this is my controller:

```
.controller('RegisterCtrl', function ($scope, $state, AuthService, $ionicPopup){      
$scope.signup = function () {
        AuthService.register(user).then(function (msg) {
          $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Register success!',
            template: "complete info form",
            okText: 'Go!'
          }).then(function(res){
            $state.go('tab.info');
          })
        }, function (errMsg) {
          $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Register failed!',
            template: errMsg
          });
          $scope.user = {};
        });
      };
```

and here is the app.js

```
  .state('tab.info', {
    url: '/user-info',
    views: {
      'tab-user-info': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/userInfo.html',
        controller: 'infoCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: do you added : <div ui-view="tab-user-info"></div>

Comment: @Ved  where should I add it ?  it is an ionic app, the info tab is an ion-view with ion-content

Comment: I guess for named view you need to add it main view.